# Why did my icons turn gray and my system hangs?

Tags: 20.04, icons

After my last Ubuntu update (yesterday), my system has been working atypically; first, at some point the entire system icons turned gray and I was unable to do anything to get them back to normal, meaning the entire system freezes and I have to abruptly restart it. On the other hand, when I start the computer it prompts a message saying that there’s not boot order assigned /found ...“initializing defaults”.
I would appreciate some help since I’ve been working on a very important project and I have to do back-up constantly fearing my whole info will disappear… thanks in advance.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Type: 64 bits
GNOME version: 3.36.8
WS: X11
Last update: APR 21th around 7p.m. GTM-5

Comment: *I’ve been working on a very important project and I have to do back-up constantly fearing my whole info will disappear* That what backups are for. Do that before anything else.

Comment: I also experienced the issue of screen turning gray and system freeze twice in last few days. There is no option but to reboot. I am using ubuntu 21.1 with kde plasma desktop and wayland mode. no update pending.